# How to mathematically find the nearest odd month below

Tags: powershell, date-arithmetic

PowerShell returns the current month with:

```
(Get-Date).Month
```

But I need to know the nearest odd month below.

If each month is represented by the matching number inside a year:

```
 1 →  1
 2 →  1
 3 →  3
 4 →  3
 5 →  5
 6 →  5
 7 →  7
 8 →  7
 9 →  9
10 →  9
11 → 11
12 → 11
```

Comment: `[int][Math]::Floor(((Get-Date).Month - 1) / 2) * 2 + 1`

Comment: Oh! You found it the way I was searching for... Now I have two valid solutions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if divisible by 2:

```
$m = (Get-Date).Month
if ($m % 2 -eq 0) { 
  $m -= 1 
} 

Write-Host $m
```

Proof:

```
1..12 | % { Write-Host -nonewline "$_ ==> " ; if ($_ % 2 -eq 0 ) { $_ -= 1} ; Write-Host $_ }
```

Comment: Fine! Thank you :-)
Was strugling since a few hours with quotient, modulo, trying to add or remove 1 from the result...

Comment: You're welcome! Please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped solve the problem

Comment: I did, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputations...
Furthermore, somebody has voted my question as not useful, which lowered my reputation... lol

Comment: @Luke AFAIK, you should be able to accept answer to your question no matter how low your reputation is. You should also get some rep points for doing so.